# SaopUI GroovyScript - How to modify request XML located in another TestCase?

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am trying to modify a request from another testCase and I'm unable to get its XML.

I'd like to know the parameter pattern to get it with this method :

```
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( targetStep.getName() + "#Request" )
```

This method seems to look for "targetStep" in its own testCase. I'd like to know how to specify to this method that I'm looking for "targetStep" in a specific testCase.

If it's not possible that way, I'd like to know how to get the XML Content of a testStep in a specific testCase in order to modify node values.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an alternative :

```
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( targetStep.getPropertyValue("request") )  
holder.setNodeValue("//NodeName",'newValue')
holder.updateProperty()
targetStep.getHttpRequest().setRequestContent(holder.getXml())
```